# 502 bad gateway error for kubernetes nginx ingress controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

Im trying to deploy the pgadmin web app on EKS cluster . I have deployed the nginx ingress controller with ingressClass on EKS cluster , still getting connection refused error

here are the env details :

**AWS EKS version : 1.23**

**nginx ingress controller :**

**pgadmin : 4.6.3**

**Ingress details :**

```
root@CS-a:~/pgadmin# kubectl describe ingress ingress-pgadmin -n pgadmin
Name:             ingress-pgadmin
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=pgadmin
                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=pgadmin
                  app.kubernetes.io/version=1.16.0
                  helm.sh/chart=pgadmin-0.1.0
Namespace:        pgadmin
Address:          acbf4d28b520b6f0b1-1450974932.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Ingress Class:    pgadmin-nginx-002
Default backend:  <default>
TLS:
  pgadmin4.abc.com-tls terminates pgadmin4.abc.com
Rules:
  Host                        Path  Backends
  ----                        ----  --------
  pgadmin4.oneenterprise.com
                              /   serv-pgadmin:80 (10.0.7.67:8080)
Annotations:                  cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-pgadmin
                              kubernetes.io/tls-acme: true
                              meta.helm.sh/release-name: pgadmin
                              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: pgadmin
                              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: 16m
                              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 16m
Events:                       <none>
```

****error log (connection refused)**

```
- 8320c1ba15b9e5be49107f8f9f8e294e
2023/07/12 19:05:54 [error] 173#173: *311075 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: pgadmin4.oneenterprise.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://10.0.7.67:8080/", host: "pgadmin4.oneenterprise.com"
2023/07/12 19:05:54 [error] 173#173: *311075 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: pgadmin4.oneenterprise.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://10.0.7.67:8080/", host: "pgadmin4.oneenterprise.com"
2023/07/12 19:05:54 [error] 173#173: *311075 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: pgadmin4.oneenterprise.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://10.0.7.67:8080/", host: "pgadmin4.oneenterprise.com"
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jul/2023:19:05:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 502 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.1823.67" 451 0.004 [pgadmin-serv-pgadmin-80] [] 10.0.7.67:8080, 10.0.7.67:8080, 10.0.7.67:8080 0, 0, 0 0.000, 0.000, 0.004 502, 502, 502 1ce73f601896618f2b2cdcfe21c93fe6
```

**ingress details :**

```
root@CS-a:~# kubectl get ingress -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                        CLASS               HOSTS
                                     ADDRESS                                                                   PORTS     AGE
pgadmin       ingress-pgadmin             pgadmin-nginx-002   pgadmin4.abc.com
                                     acbe68b1-1450974932.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80, 443   5h18m
```

I have checked the pod and containers , they are running

I have verified the service and backed configuration , they seems correct

I have verified the exposed ports and certificate , they also seems ok

now, not sure what is missing and what needs to be corrected . please suggest